# Getting Array Value from '000000002556fd3400000000051f11d7 => ' in typo3

Tags: typo3

[image]
I have array attached below. my question is how can I get the 'title' value

```
array(7 items) 
   uid => 7 (integer) 
   title => 'Ankoe' (5 chars) 
   description => '<h3>About Ankoe</h3> <p class="text-justify">The ANKÖE has established its
      elf step by step as a full-service provider in the procurement area. Both th
      e client and the contractor rely on the services of the ANKÖE in the entire
      `your text`reducing
      load times and improving...' (2017 chars) 
   slug => 'ankoe' (5 chars) 
   services => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorageprototypeobject (1 items) 000000002556fd3400000000051f11d7 =>
 Spw\SpwProjects\Domain\Model\Servicesprototypepersistent entity (uid=1, pid=23) 
      **title** => protected'Websites' (8 chars) 
      slug => protected'websites' (8 chars) 
      uid => protected1 (integer) 
      _localizedUid => protected1 (integer)
      modified _languageUid => protected0 (integer)
      modified _versionedUid => protected1 (integer)
      modified pid => protected23 (integer) 
      filtercategories => 'category-1' (10 chars) 
      projectimage => array(1 item) 
         0 => array(2 items) 
            identifier => '/user_upload/p166.jpg' (21 chars) 
            uid => 7 (integer)
```

Anyone know? how to get

Answer (score 1):

This array key is the SPL hash of the contained object. Please don't try to access these objects by their hash. Create some further getter methods in your domain model like:

```
public function getFirstService(): ?Service
{
    $this->services->rewind();
    if ($this->services->count()) {
        return $this->services->current();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Another solution to get ObjectStorage as numbered array maybe:

```
public function getServices(): array
{
    // ObjectStorage has SplObjectHashes as key which we don't know in Fluid
    // so we convert ObjectStorage to array to get numbered keys
    $services = [];
    foreach ($this->services as $service) {
        $services[] = $service;
    }

    return $services;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it depens on context you are in and you message does not give a clue. so here are the common places you would want to access a variable:

in **PHP**:

```
$myArray['title']
```

in **Fluid Templates**:

```
{myArray.title}
```